# boost::asio::steady_timer based delay with yield context is hanging at timer.async_wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I have a cpp application which is running under a single thread boost::asio context.

the following delay logic will be called inside a class object method which is called within a boost::asio::spawn co routine

I'm trying to add a simple boost::asio::steady timer based delay in the following code but

the code hangs at the line waitTimer->async_wait(yield[ec]);

```
void asyncDelay(const uint16_t delay)

{

boost::system::error_code ec;

std::string errorMsg;

if(!waitTimer)

{

errorMsg = "wait timer not created";

log<level::ERR>(errorMsg.c_str());

throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg.c_str());

}

errorMsg = "wait timer delay : " + std::to_string(delay);

log<level::ERR>(errorMsg.c_str());

waitTimer->expires_after(boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds(100));

log<level::INFO>("steady timer delay set");

waitTimer->async_wait(yield[ec]);

log<level::INFO>("steady timer delay done");

if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)

{

errorMsg = "wait timer aborted";

log<level::ERR>(errorMsg.c_str());

throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg.c_str());

}

else if (ec)

{

errorMsg = "wait timer failed";

log<level::ERR>(errorMsg.c_str());

throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg.c_str());

}

return;

}
```

This code is part of a class object which is inside a shared library and instanced and called from the main process.

The asyncDelay method is a member function of the class object.

The boost::asio::steady_timer is a unique pointer which is member function of the same class
and instantiated from the boost IO_context inside the constructor.

The asyncDelay method of the class object will be called in multiple boost:asio::spawn calls but each time it will be a separate instance of the class object so there is no possibility of same timer used by multiple instances.

The expected output is the delay function should return after the specified delay or return an error but not hang forever

The expected output is the delay function should return but it hangs.

Comment: Instead of fuzzy description, could you just show the code? In particular, nothing explains the `yield` nor where the `spawn` happens. You can probably make this a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in about 50 lines. With the description above it took me almost 40 minutes to figure out how you could possibly have `yield` as a member, and it ended up looking like this: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6186e367e3fa5cf, which is precisely what you'd expect.

Comment: Looking a little bit deeper into my crystal ball I'm betting you need a work guard (or rethink your interface)